# Angular - authentication service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am a newbee in angular and I would like to know how to make a AuthenticationService where I would check if user is authenticated or not. I have routes for which I want a user to be authenticated in order to be able to see them, and if they are not authenticated that they are redirected to login page. I am using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#-login-with-email-and-password) for token based authentication.

This is my app.js

```
angular.module('coop', ['ionic', 'coop.controllers', 'coop.services', 'satellizer'])

.constant('ApiEndpoint', {
  url: 'http://coop.app/api'
})

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $auth, $state, $location) {

  // Check for login status when changing page URL
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      var currentRoute = next.$$route;

      if (!currentRoute || currentRoute.requiresAuth && !AuthenticationService.authenticated) {
        $location.path('/auth');
      }
      else if (!currentRoute || !currentRoute.requiresAuth && AuthenticationService.authenticated) {
        $location.path('/front');
      }
  });

  $rootScope.logout = function() {

      $auth.logout().then(function() {

          // Remove the authenticated user from local storage
          localStorage.removeItem('user');

          // Remove the current user info from rootscope
          $rootScope.currentUser = null;
          $state.go('main.auth');
      });
    }

  $rootScope.token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      // StatusBar.styleDefault();
      StatusBar.show();
      StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
      StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#2a2e34");
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, ApiEndpoint) {

  $authProvider.loginUrl = ApiEndpoint.url + '/authenticate';

  $stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
    requiresAuth: true
  })

  .state('main.auth', {
    url: '/auth',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthController',
        requiresAuth: false
      }
    }
  })

  .state('main.front', {
    url: '/front',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main-front.html',
        controller: 'FrontPageController',
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  })

  .state('main.article', {
    url: '/article/{id}',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main-article.html',
        controller: 'ArticleController',
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/front');
});
```

And my controllers:

```
angular.module('coop.controllers', [])

.controller('FrontPageController', function($scope, ArticleService, $state) {
  ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.articles = data;
    $scope.like = function(article){
      article.like = article.like == 0 ? 1 : 0;
      ArticleService.like(article.id, article.like)
    };
  })
})

.controller('ArticleController', function($scope, ArticleService, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $auth) {
  ArticleService.get($stateParams.id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.article = response;
    $scope.commentsCount = response.comments.length;
    $scope.articleText = response.text;

    $scope.like = function(){
      $scope.article.like = $scope.article.like == 0 ? 1 : 0;
      ArticleService.like($scope.article.id, $scope.article.like)
    };

    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
  })

})

.controller('AuthController', function($scope, $location, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $http, $state, $auth, $rootScope) {
    $scope.loginData = {}
    $scope.loginError = false;
    $scope.loginErrorText;

    $scope.login = function() {
        var credentials = {
            email: $scope.loginData.email,
            password: $scope.loginData.password
        }

        $auth.login(credentials).then(function(response) {
            var token = JSON.stringify();
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
              disableBack: true
            });

            $state.go('main.front');
        }, function(){
            $scope.loginError = true;
            $scope.loginErrorText = error.data.error;
        });
    }
});
```

**Updated code**

I have changed the app.js as suggested:

```
// Check for login status when changing page URL
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    var currentRoute = next.$$route;

    if (!currentRoute || currentRoute.requiresAuth && !$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      $location.path('/main/login');
    }
    else if (!currentRoute || !currentRoute.requiresAuth && $auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      $location.path('/main/front');
    }
  });
```

And have added logout controller to delete user and token from localstorage, but I am still not being redirected to login page:

My controller:

```
.controller('AuthController', function($scope, $location, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $http, $state, $auth, $rootScope) {
  $scope.loginData = {}
  $scope.loginError = false;
  $scope.loginErrorText;

  $scope.login = function() {
    var credentials = {
        email: $scope.loginData.email,
        password: $scope.loginData.password
    }

    $auth.login(credentials).then(function(response) {
        var token = JSON.stringify();
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: true
        });

        $state.go('main.front');
    }, function(){
        $scope.loginError = true;
        $scope.loginErrorText = error.data.error;
    });
  }

  $scope.logout = function() {
    $auth.logout().then(function() {
      // Remove the authenticated user from local storage
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      localStorage.removeItem('token');

      // Remove the current user info from rootscope
      $rootScope.currentUser = null;
      $state.go('main.login');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using satellizer, it already takes care of this for you.

Use the isAuthenticated() method of satelizer's $auth service instead of defining your own

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  var currentRoute = next.$$route;

  if (!currentRoute || currentRoute.requiresAuth && !$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    $location.path('/auth');
  }
  else if (!currentRoute || !currentRoute.requiresAuth && $auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    $location.path('/front');
  }
```

});

Basically what $auth.isAuthenticated() does is checking if the user has a vaild jwt saved, and returns true or false.

The $routeChangeStart handler kicks in in every route change, checks if the route has requiresAuth set and if isAuthenticated returns true or false and acts accordingly.

If you want to do it on your own, here is a good tutorial on how to decode the token and check if it's valid:
https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth

Comment: I think what you have suggested would be perfect and I have done like you said, but when I go to my main/front page I am still not being redirected to login page.

Comment: You might have to delete the token from localstorage manually if you've logged in previously and didn't log out.

Comment: Also, in your AuthController, if you need to set the token manually, use $auth.setToken() of satellizer instead of localStorage.setItem(), but if I recall correctly $login will set it automatically for you.

Comment: I have updated my code, and have tried to test it after loggin out, but I am still not being redirected when I go to some pages that demaned user to be authenticated

Comment: Getting a bit out of scope, here are some ideas:
- do not use  localStorage.removeItem('user') or manipluate localstorage directly, satellizer has methods for these like $auth.logout(). and it's window.localStorage.
- use chrome dev tools or similar to check if your token is created and destroyed in localstorage after logging in and out
- add console.logs near $location.path to see if you get there in your code when needed
- use event.preventDefault() on routeChangeStart when you want to block the original navigation attempt
-plunker if you need more help

Comment: since I am using ionic I had to change $routeChangeStart to $stateChangeStart and $location.paths to $state.go and everything worked later perfectly